# Como traer mes anterior al actual

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito traer el mes anterior al actual. SOLO el mes. Ejemplo: hoy es 10-1-2020 necesito traer solo el '1'.

He intentado con `'1.month.ago'` pero eso me devuelve la fecha y hora completa, de esta manera: `'2019-12-10 13:00:00 -0300'`

Alguna solucion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente agrega `month` para obtener el mes de la cadena que tienes; e.g:

```
actual = Time.parse('2019-12-10 13:00:00 -0300')
#=> 2019-12-10 13:00:00 -0300

actual.month
#=> 12
```

Para obtener el mes anterior tomando la fecha actual<sup>1</sup>:

```
1.month.ago.month
#=> 12
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Dónde la fecha actual es `2020-01-10 22:32:51 +0000`*</sup>

---

> Ahora si lo que quiero traer es la fecha completa (sin la hora) del
>   mes anterior desde el primero dia del mes? Ejemplo: hoy es
>   '13/12/2020' y necesito traer el primer dia del mes anterior, es
>   decir, '01/12/2019'.

Partiendo del ejemplo anterior, podrías utilizar los métodos `beginning_of_month` y `to_date`; e.g.:

```
1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.to_date
#=> Sun, 01 Dec 2019
```

Es un objeto tipo `Date`, para representarlo como *String* simplemente utiliza el método `to_s`:

```
1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.to_date.to_s
#=> "2019-12-01"
```

También puedes aprovechar el método [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime), con el cual decides el formato (como *String*) con el que quieres que se muestre la fecha; por ejemplo:

```
1.month.ago.strftime("01/%m/%Y")
#=> "01/12/2019"
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!.Me ha servido de mucho. Ahora si lo que quiero traer es la fecha completa (sin la hora) del mes anterior desde el primero dia del mes? Ejemplo: hoy es '13/12/2020' y necesito traer el primer dia del mes anterior, es decir, '01/12/2019'

Comment: @francofernandez Agregué un ejemplo a la respuesta, espero te sirva.

Comment: Si, eso mismo utilice, dejo el ejemplo de lo que use aquí:
  1.month.ago.to_date.at_beginning_of_month (primer dia del mes anterior al actual)
  1.month.ago.to_date.end_of_month (Ultimo dia del mes anterior al actual)